# Appending elements to a map

Tags: ocaml

```ml
let interp_fundef (d: Ast.fundef) (g: FStore.t) : FStore.t = 
  match d with
  | Ast.FunDef (x, pl, e) -> (FStore.add x (pl, e) g)

let interp (p: Ast.prog) : Value.t = 
  let g = FStore.empty in
  let s = Store.empty in
  match p with
  | Ast.Prog (dl, e) ->
    let _ = 
      let rec fdef defl =
        match defl with
        | [] -> ()
        | h1::t1 -> 
          let _ = (interp_fundef h1 g) in
          (fdef t1)
      in fdef dl;
    in interp_expr e g s
```

### fStore.ml

```ml
module M = Map.Make(String)

type t = (string list * Ast.expr) M.t

let add = M.add

let mem = M.mem

let find = M.find

let empty = M.empty
```

### ast.ml

```ml
type fundef = FunDef of string * string list * expr
type prog = Prog of fundef list * expr
```

I'm making an f1vae interpreter in OCaml.
In the above code, I intended to make an `fstore` map which is storing all `fundef`,
before interpreting the expression in `prog`.

How can I append `fundef` to `g` one by one?
I want the `interp_fundef` to be unchanged.

Comment: Why are you throwing away the result of `interp_fundef` in `interp`? I don't really know what your code is trying to do - your variable names are meaningless and you have no comments, but I don't see why you would create an updated map and then discard it.

Comment: i want to use it but i cant get the method how

Comment: Do you know how updating a map works? Get to grips with that first perhaps. https://ocaml.org/docs and https://dev.realworldocaml.org/ are both good starting places

Comment: If you read up at dev.realworldocaml.org be aware that the `Map` module in the Base library is not the same as the `Map` module in Stdlib.

Answer (score 1):

A map is a functional data structure in OCaml. By "functional" it is meant that the data structure is immutable. We cannot mutate an existing map, but rather create a new map with changes and let the garbage collector take care of older versions of the map which are no longer referenced in a program.

A simple example:

```
module M = Map.Make (String)

let m = M.add "Baz" 36 (M.add "bar" 27 (M.add "foo" 42 M.empty))

(* Or equivalently *)

let m =
  M.empty
  |> M.add "foo" 42
  |> M.add "bar" 27
  |> M.add "Baz" 36
```

At each stage a new map is created and then passed to `M.add`.

You could really write a recursive function to handle adding values in another data structure like a list to a map, or use one of the existing functions to do so.